# Check for words counts in the string and remove the words with less count - Hive

Tags: sql, hive

Suppose I have the following as the table,

```
date_part             string_word                          id
2017-08-08       India America Advance Apartments           1
2017-08-08       Apartments Planner Headlines               1
2017-08-08       India America Headlines Gucci              1
2017-08-08       Images Same Thing Africa                   2
2017-08-08       Images                                     2
2017-08-07       India America Advance Apartments           2
2017-08-07       Apartments Planner Headlines               3
2017-08-07       India America Headlines Gucci              3
2017-08-07       Images Same Thing Africa                   3
2017-08-07       Images                                     4
```

Now I want to find the word count for each day and remove the words with less count. To find the word count, I wrote the following query,

```
SELECT date_part, word, COUNT(*) as total_word_count
FROM table_name LATERAL VIEW explode(split(string_word, ' ')) lTable as word 
where date_part > '2017-08-05'
GROUP BY date_part, word
```

This would give the following,

```
date_part       word        total_word_count
2017-08-08      India            2
2017-08-08      America          2
2017-08-08      Advance          1
2017-08-08      Apartments       2
2017-08-08      Planner          1
2017-08-08      Headlines        2
2017-08-08      Gucci            1
2017-08-08      Images           2
2017-08-08      Same             1
2017-08-08      Thing            1
2017-08-08      Africa           1
2017-08-07      India            2
2017-08-07      America          2
2017-08-07      Advance          1
2017-08-07      Apartments       2
2017-08-07      Planner          1
2017-08-07      Headlines        2
2017-08-07      Gucci            1
2017-08-07      Images           2
2017-08-07      Same             1
2017-08-07      Thing            1
2017-08-07      Africa           1
```

Now I want to remove the words with count less than 2. i.e the words with 1 count should be removed on each date. The following should be the output,

```
date_part             string_word                          id
2017-08-08       India America Apartments                   1
2017-08-08       Apartments Headlines                       1
2017-08-08       India America Headlines                    1
2017-08-08       Images                                     2
2017-08-08       Images                                     2
2017-08-07       India America Apartments                   2
2017-08-07       Apartments Headlines                       3
2017-08-07       India America Headlines                    3
2017-08-07       Images                                     3
2017-08-07       Images                                     4
```

Here the words with 1 count has been removed. This is the output which I am looking to get and this has to be with each day as well.

Can anybody help me in doing this ?

Thanks

Comment: Add `HAVING total_word_count > 1` to the query...

Comment: @usagi Filtering that is fine. But I want to remove the words from the original table. The one which has more than 1 count only should be present. The remaining words should be removed. That's the question I am looking at

Answer (score 0):

```
select      t.date_part
           ,regexp_replace(t.string_word,concat('\\s?\\b(',e.words,')\\b'),'')    as string_word
           ,t.id

from                    table_name  as t

            join       (select      date_part
                                   ,concat_ws('|',collect_list (col)) as words

                        from       (select      date_part
                                               ,e.col

                                    from        table_name t
                                                lateral view explode(split(t.string_word,'\\s+')) e

                                    group by    date_part
                                               ,e.col

                                    having      count(*) = 1
                                    ) e

                        group by    date_part
                        ) e

            on          e.date_part =
                        t.date_part
;
```

---

```
+-------------+---------------------------+-----+
|  date_part  |        string_word        | id  |
+-------------+---------------------------+-----+
| 2017-08-07  | India America Apartments  | 2   |
| 2017-08-07  | Apartments Headlines      | 3   |
| 2017-08-07  | India America Headlines   | 3   |
| 2017-08-07  | Images                    | 3   |
| 2017-08-07  | Images                    | 4   |
| 2017-08-08  | India America Apartments  | 1   |
| 2017-08-08  | Apartments Headlines      | 1   |
| 2017-08-08  | India America Headlines   | 1   |
| 2017-08-08  | Images                    | 2   |
| 2017-08-08  | Images                    | 2   |
+-------------+---------------------------+-----+
```